# MPI send and receive after task is completed. Is it even possible?

Tags: fortran, mpi, hpc

I am using the following code to run jobs in parallel. However, I was wondering if there was a way for a processor to send/receive a message after it completes a job. With this code, if I request 4 processors but have 56 job to complete, it only completes 4 jobs and then ends. I was wondering if there was a way to add to the code so all task are completed. I think a processor would need to send a message to the master processor telling it that the job is completed, send me another job if there are tjob left. I hope that makes sense. I am sorta stuck... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can... this is called a master/slave approach or dynamic parallelism. proc0 (the master, typically) will send out work to all the other procs. Then it will start waiting. As soon as one proc completes, it will collect the results and send back a new task, if available.

This kind of pseudocode:

```
if(myid.eq.0) then
  pending_tasks = 0
  sent_tasks = 0
  DO i=1,(numprocs-1)
    read(100,'(A)') command
    call MPI_SEND(command,200,MPI_CHAR,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    pending_tasks = pending_tasks + 1
    sent_tasks = sent_tasks + 1
  ENDDO
  // all procs have one task to work on.
  DO
    // wait for results - from any source
    call MPI_RECV(result,200,MPI_CHAR,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,istatus,ierr)
    free_proc = istatus(MPI_SOURCE)
    if (sent_tasks < nlines) then
      read(100,'(A)') command
      call MPI_SEND(command,200,MPI_CHAR,free_proc,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      sent_tasks = sent_tasks + 1
    else
      // all tasks sent, but wait all the results
      pending_tasks = pending_tasks - 1
    endif
    call process_and_save_result(result)
    if (penging_tasks == 0) EXIT
  ENDDO
  // in this point the master can send out the 'QUIT' command to all the slaves
else
  DO
    call MPI_RECV(command,200,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,istatus,ierr)
    // that's a suggestion for a clean exit policy - pseudocode, don't forget
    if (command=='QUIT') EXIT
    call do_work(command, result)
    call MPI_SEND(result, 200,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  ENDDO
endif
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
```

note: don't use the tag (set it to 0) if you don't need it.

see:

https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node35.htm

https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/dynamic-receiving-with-mpi-probe-and-mpi-status/

Eventually proc0 can perform some task in the while, as an optimization, using `mpi_irecv()`, `mpi_test()`, `mpi_wait()`.

Comment: Wow... this.. is.. amazing

Comment: I don't see the rationale of posting a new question with my answer... but that's it - not a problem at all. The two mentioned routines are your duty! They must do what their names suggest. "pseudocode" means: "this code is not supposed to work but to give you an idea on how to structure it"

Comment: do_work(command, result): get the command, work on it locally and fill the result. Here I've set the same type of the command, but it could be just an integer, an array,... I don't know your problem! process_and_save_result(result): get the result and process it. Print it. Save it to disk. Accumulate all the results... again, depend on you problem.

Comment: At the time, I wasn't sure what pseudocode meant. After I took a break, I realized what you meant. I think I know what I need to do now!! Thanks for explaining that for me. I really appreciate the help! I will post something if I get stuck again.